# SQL most frequent values on multiple columns group by other column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm struggling with a query to solve this:
I have this data in athena AWS

```
 name   | hobby    | food   | other_col
 cris   | sports   | pasta  |  sdsd
 cris   | music    | pizza  |  qfrfe
 cris   | sports   | pizza  |  dcfrfe
 cris   | sports   | pizza  |  koioio
 arnold | sports   | pasta  |  joiuhiu
 arnold | art      | salad  |  ojouju
 arnold | art      | pasta  |  jiojo
 jenny  | dance    | sushi  |  sdkwdk
 jenny  | dance    | sushi  |  lkjlj
 jenny  |  ski     | pizza  |  sdkwdk
 jenny  | dance    | pasta  |  jlkjlkj
```

And i need to get the most frequents values in columns group by name, something like this:

```
name   | hobby   | food  |
cris   | sports  | pizza |
arnold | art     | pasta |
jenny  | dance   | sushi |
```

Anyone could help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#complex-grouping-operations) to determine the max counts in every group (name-hobby and name-food) and then use `MAX_BY` to get the maximum:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(name, hobby, food) as (
    values ('cris'  , 'sports', 'pasta'),
        ('cris'  , 'music' , 'pizza'),
        ('cris'  , 'sports', 'pizza'),
        ('cris'  , 'sports', 'pizza'),
        ('arnold', 'sports', 'pasta'),
        ('arnold', 'art'   , 'salad'),
        ('arnold', 'art'   , 'pasta'),
        ('jenny' ,'dance'  ,'sushi'),
        ('jenny' ,'dance'  ,'sushi'),
        ('jenny' , 'ski'   ,'pizza'),
        ('jenny' ,'dance'  ,'pasta')
)

-- query
select name,
       max_by(hobby, if(hobby is not null, cnt)) hobby,
       max_by(food, if(food is not null, cnt)) food
from (select name,
             hobby,
             food,
             count(*) cnt
      from dataset
      group by grouping sets ((name, hobby), (name, food)))
group by name;
```

Output:

| name | hobby | food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jenny | dance | sushi |
| cris | sports | pizza |
| arnold | art | pasta |

Another approach - use `histogram` and some map functions magic to determine [maximum element in the map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73070009/2501279):

```sql
-- query
select name,
       map_keys(
               map_filter(
                       h,
                       (k, v) -> v = array_max(map_values(h))))[1] hobby,
       map_keys(
               map_filter(
                       f,
                       (k, v) -> v = array_max(map_values(f))))[1] food
from (select name,
             histogram(hobby) h,
             histogram(food)  f
      from dataset
      group by name);
```